# Incombrehensible error messasge when installing Tensorflow on a Nvidia Jetson TX2

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, nvidia-jetson

I am quite new to operating a linux system so please bear with me. I tried installing Tensorflow on my Jetson according to this [guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html). 
Unfortunately at step 2.4

```
$ sudo pip3 install -U numpy==1.16.1 future==0.17.1 mock==3.0.5 h5py==2.9.0 keras_preprocessing==1.0.5 keras_applications==1.0.8 gast==0.2.2 futures protobuf pybind11
```

i first get this output,

```
Collecting numpy==1.16.1
Using cached numpy-1.16.1.zip (5.1 MB)
Processing /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c1/68/2b/e3decbcfd5353f4a661ffa73d73894b070ef21427a8bee82fd/future-0.17.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mock==3.0.5
Using cached mock-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting h5py==2.9.0
Using cached h5py-2.9.0.tar.gz (287 kB)
```

but then the console freezes up for 2-4 minutes and afterwards i get this huge error message which i do not understand. Could anyone explain to me what's wrong and what i can do to fix the issue?

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f4yysrhz/h5py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-f4yysrhz/h5py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-f4yysrhz/h5py/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-f4yysrhz/h5py/
Complete output (298 lines):
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpt471vgtd
         cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy
    Complete output (262 lines):
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_sfc64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random/_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    customize UnixCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    /bin/sh: 1: svnversion: not found
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib', '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifc
    Could not locate executable lf95
    Could not locate executable pgfortran
    Could not locate executable f90
    Could not locate executable f77
    Could not locate executable fort
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable g95
    Could not locate executable pathf95
    Could not locate executable nagfor
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath' to include_dirs.
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath/ieee754.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_complex.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h']
    building library "npysort" sources
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h
      adding 'build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common' to include_dirs.
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/quicksort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/mergesort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/timsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/heapsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/radixsort.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/selection.c
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/npysort/binsearch.c
    None - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common/npy_sort.h', 'build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common/npy_partition.h', 'build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/common/npy_binsearch.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_tests" sources
    creating build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/multiarray
    conv_template:> build/src.linux-aarch64-3.5/numpy/core/src/multiarray/_multiarray_tests.c
    building extension "numpy.core._multiarray_umath" sources
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    /tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    /tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    /usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 257, in <module>
        main()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 240, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 110, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        self.run_setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 250, in run_setup
        self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 143, in run_setup
        exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
      File "setup.py", line 488, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "setup.py", line 480, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 171, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/command/dist_info.py", line 31, in run
        egg_info.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/egg_info.py", line 26, in run
        self.run_command("build_src")
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 146, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 163, in build_sources
        self.build_extension_sources(ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 320, in build_extension_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
      File "/tmp/pip-wheel-sfv14zjb/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 380, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 430, in generate_config_h
        moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 49, in check_types
        out = check_types(*a, **kw)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 288, in check_types
        "install {0}-dev|{0}-devel.".format(python))
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpt471vgtd Check the logs for full command output.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp72zlaymg', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-f4yysrhz/h5py/setup.py", line 168, in <module>
    cmdclass = CMDCLASS,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 687, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
    replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 743, in fetch_build_egg
    return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
    raise DistutilsError(str(e))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp72zlaymg', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.7']' returned non-zero exit status 1
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Ty
Michael

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem installing `h5py` on my Jetson Xavier (JetPack 4.21 L4T R32.2 release).
I eliminated this problem by:

- install `subversion` by `sudo apt-get install subversion`
- then `ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h` to resolve `xlocale.h: No such file or directory` issue.
- Finally, `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev` to fix `error: Unable to load dependency HDF5`

After that `h5py` installed successfully.

Comment: Your simple steps saved me. I already was struggling 2 days on the same issue.